# Where does Spark store RDD´s and Spark Dataframes within ongoing Spark Application

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am running Spark in Kubernetes as Standalone Spark Cluster Manager with two Spark Workers. I use Jupyter to set up  Spark Applications. The DeployMode is set to "Client" so when the driver process is generated it will run in the Pod where Jupyter runs. We read from Amazon S3 Proxy a CSV file with request.get and transform it to a RDD and afterwards to a Spark Dataframe. For reading the CSV file from S3 we are not using the spark.read method but request.get(). The whole Process from reading to Spark Dataframe happens in a function which returns the Dataframe.

```
S3PROXY == Url to proxy
def loadFromS3intoSparkDataframe(s3PathNameCsv):
    s3_rdd = spark2.sparkContext.parallelize(
                requests.get(S3PROXY + "/object", params="key={0}".format(s3PathNameCsv)).content.decode("UTF-8").split('\n'),24
            ).map(lambda x: x.split(','))
    header = s3_rdd.first()
    return s3_rdd.filter(lambda row:row != header).toDF(header)
```

The RAM consumption for keeping this Spark Dataframe stored is 5 gb, the source CSV File is only 1 gb in size. The 5gb RAM consumption remains in the Driver Process. Some co-workers of mine say, there should be an option to permanently transfer the in memory storage to the Spark-Worker Nodes, to the Spark Executors. As far as i understood, this is only possible as copy with persist() or cache().

So my question is, is my understanding correct that by default the RDDs and Dataframes are stored in the driver process memory? And if so, is it possible to transfer the variables throughout the whole existence of the Spark Application to the executors? And is the 1 to 5 gb DataTransformation uncommon?

Solution:

We die not use the right approach to load the csv. If you do not want to store the data in the driver memory you have the use the spark.read.csv() function.